# bootstrap modal not displaying information retrieved

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a very basic simple modal which is provided by Bootstrap.
I am trying to get this work but for some reason it does not return the value which is stored in the data-id and everything looks exactly the same as it does on the bootstrap tutorial. I don't think it's even using the javascript. I have tried to put the javascript in another file as well as in the same html file.

Why is it not working?

Bootstrap version (Varying modal content based on trigger button): http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var recipient = button.data('id');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h4>Testing Bootstrap Modal</h4>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@test1">Open modal for @test1
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@test2">Open modal for @test2
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@test3">Open modal for @test3
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Do you have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: javascript is enabled because i have a different html which uses jQuery to add additional rows dynamically and that works fine.

no errors in the console. I'm using safari web developer tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the script in a document ready function as:

```
$(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('id');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3kr8jft/

Comment: just tried this and unfortunately it still doesn't work :( not sure what I'm doing wrong. any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: you are magic. Not sure what you did in the jsfiddle but i just copied and pasted that into my sublime text and it's worked fantastically. thank you very much!

Comment: Quick question, when i move this into a separate file and reference it like so: <script src='js/indexcopy.js'></script> it doesn't work. any ideas why?

Comment: You might want to try jQuery no conflict approach as: 

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
});

Comment: oh okay, where would that go in the jQuery code? the first line? I'm new to jQuery and this is probably the first time I've heard of a no conflict approach lol

Comment: You would basically only need to update the current wrapper.  Check this update to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/q3kr8jft/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71948/discussion-between-user90210-and-heri-hehe-setiawan).

Comment: if i wanted to get another piece of information into the modal would i need to copy and paste the same code again but for the second value? or is there a way to append another?

Comment: You will need to add: the new data- attribute into the buttons, and declare the new var to get the info, so you can just make the changes into the current function, as:

    ...
    var recipient = button.data('id');
    var new_stuff = button.data('stuff');

Comment: I've 3 inputs. How can I add? Tried modal.find('.modal-body input[name="bsvr_egitim"]').val(recipient) but doesn't work.

Comment: You could try $.each, `modal.find('.modal-body input[name="bsvr_egitim"]').each(function(){ $(this).val(recipient)});`

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this problem. I copied and pasted the example directly from the Bootstrap page ( http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target ) and it wouldn't work. After a lot of experimentation, I finally figured out that the JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 ...
});
```

must be placed in your source AFTER the jQuery library is loaded. The standard bootstrap template puts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

right at the end of the code, which means the function appears before it in the code and it doesn't run. Once I moved the modal function to the end of my .html after the JavaScript includes, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was trying to implement the [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) example with Bootstrap 5.2. I got it to work by making sure the

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

came after my code for the modal popup.